# GridSearchCV and its feature importance

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

In gridsearchCV, when I fit like something as follows:

```
forest_reg = RandomForestRegressor()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(forest_reg, param_grid,cv=5,scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error')
grid_search.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

and after that,
when I execute this,

```
GridSearch.best_estimator_.feature_importances_
```

it gives an array of values 
so my question is what values does `GridSearch.best_estimator_.feature_importances_` this line return??

Comment: Please optimize the formatting of your question

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do spend a minute to learn how to properly format your code

Comment: Yeah..! I will do it from now onwards.. sorry for above.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `GridSearch.best_estimator_.feature_importances_` returns a `RandomForestRegressor` object.

Therefore, according to `RandomForestRegressor` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html):

> feature_importances_ : array of shape = [n_features]
>   Return the feature importances (the higher, the more important the feature).

In other words, it returns the most important features according to your training set `X_train`. Each element of `feature_importances_` corresponds to one feature of `X_train` (e.g: first element of `feature_importances_` refers to the first feature/column of `X_train`).

The higher the value of an element in `feature_importances_`, the more important is the feature in `X_train`.

Comment: Yeah. But what I want to know is what exactly these values are that feature_importances returns? I mean on what basis these values are calculated ?